# Formatting float value in C language

Tags: c, printf, output-formatting

I need to print `.5` as `0.5` using the `printf` statement in C language.
It can be done easily using  the following code.

```
printf("%03f", myfloatvalue);
```

But the situation is `myfloatvalue` is dynamic. So i am not sure whether it is a 3 character number, it could be `.5` or `.56` or `.567`. In the above cases i need to print as `0.5`, `0.56`, and `0.567`.

Comment: I need to show 0.123456 ..So can i use printf("%0*f",places,myfloatvalue);

Comment: There is no (exact) float representation of 0.56 or 0.567.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from my comment to Florian's answer, the format of `"%0g"` will print the shortest representation with the leading-zero, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    float f[] = { .5, .56, .567 };
    size_t n = sizeof f/sizeof *f;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%0g\n", f[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/floatfmt
0.5
0.56
0.567
```

Comment: How is "%0g" different from "%g"? There's no minimum width specified, so the number will never be padded.

Comment: It prints the leading **zero** in front of the decimal `:)` E.g `man printf` *"0   The value should be zero padded.  For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g"*

Comment: The C standard says it means: "leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding". Since the field width is unspecified and there's no padding it does nothing. You can test by trying `printf("%g", 0.4);` which I think you think will output `.4` but will actually output `0.4`.

Comment: Paul, don't get me wrong, I see what you are saying, and I agree with it. I also agree, that nowhere in `man printf` does in guarantee the printing of a leading zero. In fact in many cases, including the `.`, will not be printed absent a significant digit for that position. The only guaranteed way I can see to insure the zero is printed is with the `%0g`. It is in no way an error to include it. I get the padding argument, but I also note the lack of guarantee of the zero printing without it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Adding `0` is not needed.  `"%g"` for OP's numbers starts like `"%f"` and that is specified ( guaranteed) to "If a decimal-point
character appears, at least one digit appears before it." so always a leading 0.

Answer (score 6):

`%g` does print the shortest possible representation of a float.

```
printf("%g",myfloatvalue);
```

Comment: Almost, `"%0g"`, would do it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [Disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263242/formatting-float-value-in-c-language#comment79493574_46263402) that a 0 is needed.